# extending class in python 2.7, usage of super()

Tags: python, inheritance, python-2.7

Perhaps this is a silly question, but why doesn't this code work in python 2.7?

```
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser

class MyParser(ConfigParser):
    def __init__(self, cpath):
        super(MyParser, self).__init__()
        self.configpath = cpath
        self.read(self.configpath)
```

It fails on:

```
TypeError: must be type, not classobj
```

on the `super()` line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely because `ConfigParser` does not inherit from `object`, hence, is not a [*new-style* class](http://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/). That's why `super` doesn't work there.

Check the `ConfigParser` definition and verify if it's like this:

```
class ConfigParser(object): # or inherit from some class who inherit from object
```

If not, that's the problem.

My advice to your code is not use `super`. Just invoke directly self on the `ConfigParser` like this:

```
class MyParser(ConfigParser):
    def __init__(self, cpath):
        ConfigParser.__init__(self)
        self.configpath = cpath
        self.read(self.configpath)
```

Comment: If you look at the source for `ConfigParser.py` (2.7.4), `ConfigParser` inherits from `RawConfigParser` which is an old-style class (does not inherit from `object`).

Comment: There you go. That's the reason.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `ConfigParser` is an *old-style* class.  `super` does not work with old-style classes.  Instead, use explicit call to `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, cpath):
     ConfigParser.__init__(self)
     self.configpath = cpath
     self.read(self.configpath)
```

See [this question,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python) for example, for an explanation of new vs old style classes.

Comment: what exactly is an "old-style class"?